# Browser interpreting line breaks in code as spaces (HTML)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, whitespace

I have 6 images sized 50x50 that are supposed to fit in a 300px div (50 * 6 = 300).
In my code I write them as follows:

```
<img src="foo.png" />
<img src="foo.png" />
<img src="foo.png" />
<img src="foo.png" />
<img src="foo.png" />
<img src="foo.png" />
```

Note the line breaks in between the image tags. I write them that way for clarity.
The problem is that when I test the page in a browser - the images do not fit, because the browser adds a space for every line break so I end up with something like this:

```
[img][space][img][space][img][space][img][space][img][space][img][space]
```

instead of:

```
[img][img][img][img][img][img]
```

I can easily remove the line breaks from my html, but that makes my code a lot less readable. 
I am working in Ruby on Rails 2.3 - if there's a helper function for stripping out whitespace, I don't mind using that.

I was wondering if anybody knows how I can avoid this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your images in a `<div class="images">` and set your css rules to `div.images img { float: left }`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the image_tag helper, you can do

the `-%>` will not include the spaces in output.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I actually have tabs before each image_tag to show hierarchy in my markup, so it only works if I remove the tabs